# URL params being ignored?

Tags: html, url, parameters

Newbie programmer alert!

I'm trying to lookup a postcode programatically here: https://www.gov.uk/find-local-council

I've inspected the form submit in the network tab in Safari, and it seems the parameter is passed as postcode=SW1+0AA

So the URL I'm pasting into the browser is: https://www.gov.uk/find-local-council?postcode=SW1A+0AA

This returns me to the original page, as if the params are being ignored, instead of showing the search results page. How can I get this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I've inspected the form submit in the network tab" — I did that: https://imgur.com/a/4Xn2g0M — It is **not** in the URL.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#method

Comment: They are making a post request with a body... You are making a GET request. They did not code the page to handle querystring parameters.

Comment: I thought it was in the URL as I saw "SW1A+0AA" in the Request Data under Headers... so I've not understood that properly.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.. is there a way of programmatically calling the search and passing a postcode?